# Maximum open ssl connections on Windows

Tags: ssl, erlang

version: erlang R13B

Hi all,

how can I increase the amount of ssl ports/handles that my network server is able to create on Windows?
On linux I was able to successful create about 1000 connections using:

```
-env ERL_MAX_PORTS 80000 -P 268435456
```

and changing the maximum open fd's using ulimit.

On windows apparently there is no effect using the same configuration, and sadly the number of open connections are *VERY* small (about 30, and it opens 6 handles for each one). I've noticed that the shell starts two other children processes, inet_gethost.exe and ssl_esock.exe. If these are the ones that I have to increase the port count, how do I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111855), in Windows NT

> the maximum number of sockets
>   supported by a particular Windows
>   Sockets supplier is
>   implementation-specific. An
>   application should make no assumptions
>   about the availability of a certain
>   number of sockets.

According to [this](http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/descriptor_limits.html), you should redefine the value of **FD_SETSIZE**.

It also suggests to have a look to **WSADATA.iMaxSockets**.

Comment: These config's aren't on erlang interpreter level. I'm looking on how to increase the port amount for ssl backend programs. When I use the server using plain sockets, It can handle a thousand connections with no problem.